# Print floating point number with a set number of significant digits (non-scientific)

Tags: python, format

I want to print floating point numbers with a set number of significant (i.e. non-zero) digits, but avoid the scientific notation (`e`).

So, for example, the number `0.000000002343245345` should be printed as `0.000000002343` (and not `2.343e-09`)

I know how to define number of significant digits with an e notation:

```
>>>print('{:.3e}'.format(0.000000002343245345))
2.343e-09
```

And how to print a set number of decimal places without e-notation:

```
>>>print('{:.12f}'.format(0.000000002343245345))
0.000000002343
```

but not how to combine the two.
is there any simple way of doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code that usually does what you want.

```
x = 0.000000002343245345
n = 4

from math import log10, floor

print('{:.{}f}'.format(x, n - floor(log10(x)) - 1))
```

Note that, due to the lack of exactness in floating-point arithmetic, that this may occasionally give a wrong answer. For example, the `floor(log10())` may be one off from what is expected at or very near negative powers of 10 such as `0.1`, `0.01`, `0.001`, and so on. My code seems to work well with those values but that is not guaranteed.

Also, there is no reasonable answer for some combinations of `x` and `n`. For example, what do you expect to result from `x = 200000` and `n = 4`? There is no good answer, and my code gives the error

```
ValueError: Format specifier missing precision
```

Comment: The result for `x = 200000` and `n = 4` is `200000`. So is the result for `x = 200023` and `n = 4`. But that's pretty straight forward to implement. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to calculate the number of digits yourself. For four significant digits, this would be

```
number = 0.000000002343245345
digits = 4 - int(math.ceil(math.log10(number)))
print("{:.{}f}".format(number, digits))
# 0.000000002343
```